# Maven Compile with specific Module

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am comiling spark project with following command

```
mvn  -Phadoop2-yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.3 -Dyarn.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.3 -DskipTests clean package
```

my hadoop version is `'2.3.0-cdh5.0.3'`
It compiles well but if  errors occured how to resume compile for module example ,It prompts me  message lik this

```
mvn <goals> -rf :spark-examples_2.10
```

I have tried  :

```
 mvn  -Phadoop2-yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.3 -Dyarn.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.3 -DskipTests clean package -rf :spark-examples_2.10
```

But its not helpful,Anyone knows whether i am missing anything to compile.